# Is it possible to put a field in a CRM form without an attribute associated with the field?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to simply display a url that's created by some javascript in the forms onload event. I never actually save it to the attribute. Is there a way I can cut out the attribute and just have a blank field in my form that I can write a string too?

Typically I would do something like this:

```
        var cm_name = new xrm5.Metadata.StringAttributeMetadata()
        {
            Description = CrmHelpers.CreateLocalizedLabel("landingpage_name_description", cultures),
            DisplayName = CrmHelpers.CreateLocalizedLabel("landingpage_name_displayname", cultures),
            Format = xrm5.Metadata.StringFormat.Text,
            IsValidForAdvancedFind = new xrm5.BooleanManagedProperty(true),
            MaxLength = 250,
            RequiredLevel = new xrm5.Metadata.AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(xrm5.Metadata.AttributeRequiredLevel.ApplicationRequired),
            SchemaName = "cm_name"
        };
        cm_name.SetPrivatePropertyValue<bool>("IsPrimaryName", true);
        entityDefinition.Attributes.Add(cm_name);
```

and

```
            leftCell = Version4FormGenerator.CreateFormCell(formXmlDom, true, 0, 1, 1, "landingpage_name_displayname", cultures, "cm_name", CLASSID_TEXT_BOX, "cm_name", false, null);
```

for version 4 and

```
            leftCell = Version5FormGenerator.CreateFormCell(formXmlDom, true, 0, 1, 1, "landingpage_name_displayname", cultures, "cm_name", CLASSID_TEXT_BOX, "cm_name", false, false, null, new Guid("392b0a44-9c6e-4dba-a5a3-099e1a4b79bf"));
```

for 2011.

I want to cut the first part out and only have the last two. Is that even possible? This needs to work for both 2011 and ver 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I think would be to add an IFrame to the form with a custom HTML page, then write the value to that. In 2011 it's easier with web resources, but in 4.0 you could host it in the ISV folder.

Answer (score 0):

What about jQuery? You'd have to do some scrounging around, but you could find the element you want to place it before and append it. http://api.jquery.com/append/